# bigquery s3 data transfer service edit parameters to remove default appending records

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-transfer

I have set up a service and is working as intended however every time the service runs, there are new records that show up in the table. I want to edit the configuration to allow the service to replace all records in the destination table instead of appending records.

I don't want to use partitioned tables as I only want to use the latest data available.

But the documentation doesn't have any option to replace records instead of appending records: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/s3-transfer-intro

They do mention:
Transfers from Amazon S3 are always triggered with the WRITE_APPEND preference which appends data to the destination table. See configuration.load.writeDisposition in the load job configuration for additional details.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/s3-transfer

I don't provide see any details about "configuration.load.writeDisposition". Should I be learning the command line in order to do this?